# Error: Could not find or load main class while running .jar file

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, web-applications

I have just started programming with Java and I am trying to create a java web app. I followed this [tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/basic_app_embedded_tomcat/basic_app-tomcat-embedded.html#section10).

After completing the tutorial when I run the resulting .jar file, I receive following error.

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.employees.Main

I have searched about this error and there are multiple answers about this but I didn't manage to solve my problem. Can anyone help specifically in this case. This is the link to [source code](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/basic_app_embedded_tomcat/files/employees-app.zip).

I call the program as:

1. navigate to target directory
2. run command

> java -jar employees-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Comment: @Jens It got a main class, because you can also start a web based application through your code programmatically, as it is done here.

Comment: Show how you call the program

Comment: Did tomcat throw the exception? Spring? Keep on searching. This has been answered many times

Comment: updated question about how i call

Comment: there is no exception from tomcat.

Comment: Thanks for the accept!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Compile the code using maven `mvn clean compile assembly:single`
2. Run it using the command that you have in the question.

Comment: The result is same after running it this way, tried it before many times.